# React Native Expo: Save user Info To Firebase Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to sign up the user with firebase . as shown below.

here is the imports

```
import { auth } from "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebase from "../DataBase/FireBase/FireBase";
```

import firebase from "../DataBase/FireBase/FireBase";

```
 const [FullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");

 const signUp = async () => {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password);
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .set({
          email: currentUser.email,
         FullName,
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
        alert("There is something wrong!!!!", err.message);
    }
  }
```

the user actually can sign up. but the data is not save to the firestore database and no errors .
any suggestions please.

Comment: Try `await  db.collection("users")...set()` adding await before the promise.

Comment: it did not work . it gives an error of The caller does not have permission

Comment: Share your security rules please...

Comment: import firebase from "firebase/app";
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD120BMcOBY38i7YomVnopKjKeEIoC1RA",
    authDomain: "kdszoo-2492.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "kdszoo-249c2",
    storageBucket: "kdszoo-249c2.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "501809217975",
    appId: "1:50180927975:web:abdea6449368236d8e832",
    measurementId: "G-WR8QSQ7G2E"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;

Comment: I meant Firestore security rules.. Please visit this page and share them https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/rules

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235510/discussion-between-houcin-olmostaf-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: `write: false` means it'll never allow anyone to write to database.

Comment: oh should I make it like this :    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yes but then it'll allow everyone to write to database. Please check [Firestore security rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&t=686s)

Comment: I did that. it created an account . but still nothing is shown  in firestore

Comment: thanks man for your help now it worked .

Answer (score 1):

When your security rules are set to `allow write: if false;` then no one except the Admin SDK can write to your database. You can changed the value to true but then your data is available to anyone on the internet. Ideally you might want to restrict users to their own documents only so in that case try these security rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Now users can read/write on documents where the document ID is equal to their UID. You can read more about security rules in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: where I should add this line exactly please

Comment: @houcinolmostaf I updated the answer. just paste the whole thing in security rules. The URL that I had shared earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked for me that not using the set method would work perfectly if the add method was used. for example

```
await db.collection("users")
      .add({
            email: Email,
            name:FullName,
      });
```